# Laravel5 console not registerring

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

As part of my Laravel 5.2 application, I would like to define a custom command for artisan, but my command doesn't appear in `artisan list`.

1). I created the command skeleton: `artisan make:console --command=process:emails`

2). I added a bit of test code to the `handle()` method of the new class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\CommunicationsQueue;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class ProcessEmailQueueCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'process:email';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
    */
    protected $description = 'Send all currently pending emails in the queue';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        CommunicationsQueue::where('status', 'PENDING')->update(['status'=>'TEST']);

        $this->info('The mails queue was successfully processed.');
    }
}
```

3). Then, I registerred the command in `app/Console/Kernel.php`:

```
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\ProcessEmailQueueCommand',
];
```

What am I missing here? I'm sure it's something incredibly simple, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Just at a glance... it looks like your are not registering that command properly. App\Commands is missing, you did not type the full namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `app/Console/Kernel.php` try with the following code

```
protected $commands = [
    'App\Console\Commands\ProcessEmailQueueCommand',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

On Kernel.php, try include the full name, which should be:

```
protected $commands = [
    \App\Console\Commands\ProcessEmailQueueCommand::class,
];
```